# How can I link a pre-built library using Buck?

Tags: ios, xcode, buck

I'm trying to add a prebuilt static lib as a dependency to my iOS project using Buck. With prebuilt_cxx_library, I get it to work fine from the CLI, but when it generates the .xcodeproj file, it fails to add the right headers to the search path, so it's impossible to edit. Is there anyway to get the generated project to work?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add the appropriate `exported_headers` to your [`prebuilt_cxx_library`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/prebuilt_cxx_library.html).